# J48 algorithm shows 100% accuracy for my dataset, I need to lower this to below 90%

Tags: weka

I have a dataset and essentially my class variable is identical to the G3 variable. So, G3 are the grades of students, and then the class variable is just "pass/fail". Due to this the J48 algorithm always shows 100% accuracy when I test my class variable.

How can I fix this/lower the accuracy?

The only thing that worked is removing G3 but then the dataset wouldn't make sense as the class variable was derived from G3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to remove G3.

Right now, you aren't "predicting" anything.  Pass/Fail is just simply a recoding of the grades in G3.

I don't see how "the dataset wouldn't make sense".

Comment: Yeah, you're right, for some reason my professor said it wouldn't make sense but she ended up coming to a similar conclusion later. Another way to lower the accuracy is if the grades are categorized instead of just pass/fail (ie poor, average, good, excellent). Thank you.                                                                        On another note, do you have any tips on analyzing the dataset with J48? Mainly with cross-validation and percentage split.

Comment: Unless you have a really large dataset, 10-fold cross validation works nicely, and is the Weka default.  I'm working with a larger set now (28k observations, >200 variables), so I'm using 4 fold cross-validation because each pass is taking over 10 minutes.  The main thing I usually change is minNumObj (the minimum number of observations at a terminal node).  The default of 2 is too low and I'll usually increase that, which often improves accuracy.